# Dynamic sql not working with return table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

When I'm trying to execute regular select query it works completely fine

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_uczniowie(klasaId integer)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        kursor_uczniowie refcursor,
        uczniowie text
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    uczniowie text DEFAULT '';
    uczen record;
    kursor_uczniowie CURSOR(klasaId integer)
        FOR SELECT imie, nazwisko
        FROM testy.uczniowie
        WHERE klasa = klasaId;
BEGIN
    OPEN kursor_uczniowie(klasaId);

    LOOP
        FETCH kursor_uczniowie INTO uczen;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    uczniowie := uczniowie || '  ' || uczen.imie || ' ' || uczen.nazwisko;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE kursor_uczniowie;

    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT kursor_uczniowie, uczniowie;
END;
$$
```

[image]

But when I'm trying to do the same but with dynamic sql, it says that there's no any kursor_uczniowie or uczniowie column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_uczniowie3(klasaId integer)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        kursor_uczniowie refcursor,
        uczniowie text
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    dsql text := 'SELECT kursor_uczniowie, uczniowie';
    uczniowie text DEFAULT '';
    uczen record;
    kursor_uczniowie CURSOR(klasaId integer)
        FOR SELECT imie, nazwisko
        FROM testy.uczniowie
        WHERE klasa = klasaId;
BEGIN
    OPEN kursor_uczniowie(klasaId);

    LOOP
        FETCH kursor_uczniowie INTO uczen;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    uczniowie := uczniowie || '  ' || uczen.imie || ' ' || uczen.nazwisko;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE kursor_uczniowie;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE dsql;
END;
$$
```

[image]

Do you maybe know why it won't work and how to do this?

I think that it has to do something with the returns table, but I'm not so advanced to understand how it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using loops and cursors in the first place? That's the problem. A simple SELECT with N results will run N times faster than this cursor

Comment: These are the rules that my supervisor gave to me, I wouldn't ever make a function looking like this.

Comment: If you have an overcomplicated prodecure (not query) adding dynamic SQL will only make things worse. The error is expected. There are no such columns *in the dynamic SQL string*. That string is a separate script and has no relation to the rest of the script.

Comment: Okay, but do you know the soultion for this?

Comment: Write a proper query. What *are* you trying to do in the first place, and why is a cursor involved? This isn't a "they told me so" situation. The original code seems to only return the last row too which is probably wrong - why iterate over 100s of rows only to return the last one?

Comment: If you want to aggregate multiple rows into a single string, first, it's cheaper to do so on the client. Second, you can use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate string values, the same way you use `SUM` to aggregate numbers. `CONCAT_WS` can concatenate multiple values witha delimiter. `SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT_WS(' ',uczniowie,imie , nazwisko),' ') FROM testy.uczniowie WHERE klasa = klasaId;` probably does what you want

Comment: If you insist on using the cursor, you'll have to include it in the dynamic SQL string. That means all this code will have to go into that string.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I've already found an answer and I could just use 
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT (dsql, uczniowie, kursor_uczniowie);

Answer (score 0):

I found that I just needed to use

```
...
dsql text := 'SELECT %L,%L';
...
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT(dsql, uczniowie, kursor_uczniowie); 
...
```

and it worked.